# Not being able to find an element by xpath using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to click a button using selenium, and to select the button on the site's dropdown date picker.

[The button I wish to click is highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCpJ7.png)

> http://covid.gov.pk/stats/ict

I am using the following xpath.

> //*[@id="datepicker-1361-7562-title"]/strong

and Here is the code I am using

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import date
import time

#calculating days from first day 
d1 = date(2020, 3, 10)
dCurrent = date.today()
daysElapsed = int((dCurrent - d1).days)

#setting up driver and fetching website
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://covid.gov.pk/stats/ict')

#wait for page and resources to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@id=\"preloader\"]")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/iframe')))


driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/lego-report/lego-canvas-container/div/file-drop-zone/span/content-section/canvas-component[29]/div/div/div/div/ga-date-range-picker/lego-date-duration-control/control-layout-wrapper/button/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="datepicker-1361-7562-title"]/strong').click()
```

The problem is that I am able to click other elements on the drop down menu just not this button.

The error I encounter when I run my code.

> in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="datepicker-1361-7562-title"]/strong"}
>   (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)

I have been  trying to resolve this issue but can't seem to pin point what exactly I maybe doing wrong, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Okay I have realised my mistake, upon further inspection I found out that each time i open the drop down menu. The id for the month/year button changes. All I have to do is use other properties to select the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after switching to the frame and click on on the calendar, the first section 'startDate' you can find the year button with the following selector

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@ng-model='$ctrl.calendarDateRange.startDate']//table[@class='uib-daypicker']//button[contains(@id, 'datepicker-')]').click()
```

If you wish to click on 'enddate' section change path for  `//div[@ng-model='']`

Comment: Thank you. I should have tried another method for my selector. The xpath was using an ID to select the element, whereas each time the calendar was rendered it changed that ID due to which my code wasn't working.